# NameNotFoundException when minimizing app

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I have an Android app and when I minimize it (go to home screen) I get this error on logcat, I don't know what's causing it since it's not thrown by some line of my code. I searched online but found nothing. Any idea? Ask for more info if I didn't post it correctly.

Thank you.

```
12-19 20:45:19.091    3178-3178/? I/RemoteViews.Performance﹕ apply:com.foxygames.gcm prepareContext:4 inflateContent:56 performApply:14 actionsCount:11 bitmapMemory:0.0
12-19 20:45:19.096    3178-3178/? W/ContextImpl﹕ Failed to check package's status, pkg:com.foxygames.gcm
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.foxygames.gcm is uninstalling.
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2028)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextWrapper.java:599)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews.prepareContext(RemoteViews.java:2349)
            at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2266)
            at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.inflateViews(BaseStatusBar.java:806)
            at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.addNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1031)
            at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addNotification(PhoneStatusBar.java:1018)
            at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:290)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 20:45:19.116    3178-3178/? I/RemoteViews.Performance﹕ apply:com.foxygames.gcm prepareContext:2 inflateContent:15 performApply:5 actionsCount:16 bitmapMemory:0.0
```

Comment: Is `com.foxygames.gcm` your app? If yes, does your app have an app widget? If yes, and if you remove that app widget from your home screen, does the error go away?

Comment: Yes, it's my app, and no, it doesn't have a widget :(

Comment: Is there anything else that you are doing that might involve a `RemoteViews`, such as a custom `Notification`?

Comment: Yes, I have an IntentService (for Google Cloud Messaging) that creates a notification with NotificationCompat.Builder. Is that related to the problem? When I send a message from GCM and it app is open, the notification works well, but if I close it, I get a NullPointerException due, I guess, to the error posted here :S

Comment: I doubt that your `NullPointerException` is tied to this. Your LogCat snippet feels like a `RemoteViews` associated with your app is unhappy because it was outstanding when you re-ran your app from your IDE.